# Hashbytes some column values SQL

Tags: sql, types, hash

I have to hashbytes some columns in some tables in the db.
I am new in this field, and I was wondering, what about the applications that get data from these tables? Will this cause any issue with the length of these columns these application expect?

For ex, using hashing the value of the column First_Name "John":

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'John')
```

it becomes: `0xA8CFCD74832004951B4408CDB0A5DBCD8C7E52D43F7FE244BF720582E05241DA`, 64 characters long, instead of  previous varchar(30) for the column First_Name.

So, can I hash values, without impacting applications that already uses these data?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

no, you cannot

HASHBYTES Returns the MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA, SHA1, or SHA2 hash of its input in SQL Server.

Comment: Ok, thanks! One more question please. If I want to hash values in a column table, should I change the datatype or length of that column so the old value can be updated with the new hash value?

Comment: sure. ALTER TABLE t1 ALTER COLUMN c VARCHAR (64);